# Как корректно отобразить страницу при изменении пропорций экрана?

Tags: html5, css3

Имеется адаптивный дизайн страницы для планшетов, начиная с разрешения 960х640px. Стоит задача, чтоб при повороте девайса, сохранялось горизонтальное размещение страницы. То есть, чтоб при -90/90 градусах сохранялся горизонтальный вид. При альбомной ориентации все отображается корректно, а вот при портретной прячется часть страницы. Эмулятор в хроме будто отображается 960х960рх, но прячет 320рх остальных и появляется прокрутка вбок.

Как сделать так, чтоб страница корректно подстраивалась под изменение пропорций?

Comment: Тег `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` указан? Стиль для ширины в 640px через медиа запрос применяется?

Comment: Да. 
Может еще проблема в том, что большинство размеров указаны в %, но есть некоторые в vh. Из-за этого могут возникать какие-то конфликты?